# Ejactulation hours later

Tags: fiqh, taharah, ghusl, masturbation

I have a question regarding an issue that i couldn't find the answer for anywhere else so I decided to ask here. After masturbating (I know it is bad and I am trying to stop), I usually force the semen to not release, however after several minutes or sometimes even an hour, I see a liquid that is thin and slightly white and slightly sticky, which fits the description of madhiy. Is this considered semen or madhiy and do I have to do ghusl?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. How did you come to the conclusion it was madhiy? What description are you talking about please share this information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

As per a Zakir Naik video that I watched regarding this issue, it is not considered semen.The thin transparent fluid is pre ejaculatory fluid and does not make you impure. You don't have to perform ghusl.But if semen comes out you will have to perform ghusl.That is the ruling I think.